# EF Core relationships query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm fairly new to Entity Framework, my tables relationship looks a bit like this

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

I would like to make a query on the Customer table and include only the last Product created MAX(Id)

Normal SQL query would look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Product ON Customer.Id = Product.CustomerId
WHERE Product.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Product WHERE CustomerId = Customers.Id)
```

My current EF query look like this but it return all the products...

```
List<Customer> customers = _context.Customers
                .Include(c => c.Products)
                .ToList();
```

I tried something like this which gives me the right results, but EF makes a bunch of query and very quickly I see this seems like  wrong way to go at it

```
List<Customer> customers = _context.Customers
                .Select(c => new Customer() {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    c.Products = c.Products.Where(d => d.Id == c.Products.Max(max => max.Id)).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

I would like some suggestion, or if there's a different way to make this works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like below query can be written in a different way

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Product ON Customer.Id = Product.CustomerId
WHERE Product.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Product WHERE CustomerId = Customers.Id)
```

This can be written as

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Product ON Customer.Id = Product.CustomerId
Order by Product.Id desc
```

Assuming customer name is required,above query can be written in LINQ or using EF as below

```
var customers = _context.Customers.Join(_context.Products, cu => cu.id,
p => p.CustomerId, (cu,p) => new { cu,p})
.Select( c => new { prodId = c.p.Id,customername = c.cu.Name })
.OrderByDescending( c => c.prodId).Take(1);
```

Comment: Oh, you showed me how to use the Join properly! I couldn't get the result I wanted with the OrderByDescending().Take(1) but I replaced with .Where(c => c.p.Id == c.cu.Product.Max(max => max.Id)), and now EF generate the query I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured navigation property 1-n I would recommend you to use:

```
var customers = _context.Customers
  .SelectMany(c => c.Products, (c, p) => new { c, p })
  .Select(b => new { prodId = b.p.Id, customername = b.c.Name })
  .OrderByDescending(c => c.prodId).Take(1);
```

Much more clearer to me and looks better with multiple nested joins.